# How to know which cpu/platform basel recognizes

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to build tensorflow on aarch64 linux board computer.
But tensorflow's bazel settings use armeabi-v7a config to build libjpeg-turbo.
This cause build error `gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mfloat-abi=softfp'` (aarch64 gcc has no softfp option).
I think that bazel recognizes my build environment as android armeabi-v7a (correct is linux aarch64), but I don't know how to check that and how to control that.
Bazel does not have functions/values like as cmake's message/CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR. This is very irritating me.

Comment: What is the full command line that you are using?